# Insufficient privileges to operate on schema 'PUBLIC'

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I created a user ANALYST_USER and granted a role ANALYST.

When I tried to create a table in the TEST_DB, I got a following error message:
Unable to create table TEST.
SQL access control error: Insufficient privileges to operate on schema 'PUBLIC'

[image]

Here are the statements I wrote before trying to create a table using the ANALYST_USER account.

> USE ROLE SECURITYADMIN;
>
> -- Create Role--
> CREATE ROLE ANALYST
>
> -- Database--
> GRANT USAGE ON DATABASE TEST_DB TO ROLE ANALYST;
>
> -- Schema--
> GRANT USAGE, MONITOR ON ALL SCHEMAS IN DATABASE TEST_DB TO ROLE ANALYST;
> GRANT USAGE, MONITOR ON FUTURE SCHEMAS IN DATABASE
> TEST_DB TO ROLE ANALYST;
>
> -- Warehouse--
> GRANT USAGE ON WAREHOUSE TEST_WH TO ROLE ANALYST;
> GRANT USAGE ON WAREHOUSE TEST_WH TO ROLE ANALYST;
>
> -- Tables/Views--
> GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN DATABASE TEST_DB TO ROLE ANALYST;
> GRANT SELECT ON FUTURE TABLES IN DATABASE TEST_DB TO ROLE
> ANALYST;
>
> -- User -- GRANT ROLE ANALYST to USER ANALYST_USER;

Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

Comment: Are you using correct role on the top right of the UI?

Comment: I used an account admin to create a user.
I used security admin to create role and granted database, schema, warehouse, table, and view.

Comment: Hi , try adding this GRANT , grant all on schema TEST_DB.PUBLIC to role ANALYST;

Comment: Thank you, @HimanshuKandpal.  Following statement did the work.

GRANT ALL ON ALL SCHEMAS IN DATABASE TEST_DB TO ROLE ANALYST;
GRANT ALL ON FUTURE SCHEMAS IN DATABASE TEST_DB TO ROLE ANALYST;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because the role was missing create table rights on the public schema. You just have usage and monitor privileges in your schema grant. So, GRANT CREATE TABLE ON SCHEMA TEST_DB.PUBLIC TO ROLE ANALYST; would have solved your issue.

Answer (score 2):

Following statement solved the issue.
GRANT ALL ON ALL SCHEMAS IN DATABASE TEST_DB TO ROLE ANALYST;
GRANT ALL ON FUTURE SCHEMAS IN DATABASE TEST_DB TO ROLE ANALYST;

I understand this gives "ALL" permissions, so if we want to give only "create table" permission, then we need to use following statement instead:

Grant create table on schema IN DATABASE TEST_DB to role ANALYST;

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).